# C# Self Initated class - how to use in project

Tags: c#, arrays, class

I have created a class and self initialized it in the file - is this the best way to use it?  I have another Constant class that I can use but I am unable to use this for some reason in my project, do they need to be consts?

File: test.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;

namespace DH.Models
{
    public class test
{
        public string testSourceCollection { get; set; }
        public string testSourceKey { get; set; }
        public string testSourceDatabase { get; set; }
        public string testSourceCluster { get; set; }
        public string testSourceTimestamp { get; set; }

        public test[] testDetails = {
                    new test{
                        testSourceCollection = "SourceCollection",
                        testSourceDatabase = "SourceDatabase ",
                        testSourceKey = "SourceKey ",
                        testSourceTimestamp = "SourceTimestamp "
                    },
                    new ProviderRecon
                    {
                        testSourceCollection = "testSourceCollection2",
                        testSourceDatabase = "testSourceDatabase2",
                        testSourceKey = "testSourceKey2",
                        testSourceTimestamp = "testSourceTimestam2",
                        testSourceCluster = "testSourceCluster2"
                    }
                    };
        }
    
}
```

I would like to use in my Worker.cs file as such

```
public class Worker : BackgroundService
        {
           var test = test.testDetails;
           Console.WriteLine("2nd test: " + test.testSourceCluster )
           //Prints "2nd test: testSourceCluster2"
        }
```

Comment: You haven't self initialized a class. It's unclear what you mean by "Constant class". Can you read [ask] and try to improve the question?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to model with this, but your constructor is going to throw a `StackOverflowException` because when `testDetails` is initialized, it creates more `test` instances, each of which would create a new `testDetails`, and so on. The constructor would never get a chance to return.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably want `testDetails` to be static. You can't access (non-static) members using a type. Change `public test[] testDetails = ...` to `public static test[] testDetails =...`

However, you have a lot of non-standard namings there, which make this code confusing to read. The class `test` should be called `Test` instead. The line `var test = test.testDetails;` is hard to read otherwise (and probably won't compile). Same is true for your Worker class. That piece of code won't compile.

Answer (score 0):

Every time when you create an instance of your class, testDetails property is initialized with new array. If you create 1000 instances for each instance testDetails is initialized with new array.

You can use static field/property to avoid create multiple instances with the same array. [static keyword](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/static)

Or use static readonly property/field to avoid create multiple instances with the same array. static readonly properties/fields can be initialized with static constructors. [Static constructors](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/static-constructors)

Comment: That's not what ***effectively*** happens, though. The first element of `testDetails` that it creates is an instance of `test`, which then creates a new array for that `test` instance, and then it creates the first instance of `test` for *that* array, with no condition to tell it to stop the runaway recursion. So really, the consumer isn't going to have a chance to create more than 1 instance of their own (unless they create a thread for each one, and then they'll all abort from the `StackOverflowException`).

Comment: @madreflection you're right